# Unable to find out the variables and equations of BLT Matrix in Open Modelica

Tags: modelica, openmodelica

I tried getting out the BLT matrix of the Modelica>Thermal>Fluidflow>Onemass using the bltmatrixdump flag.

I see the BLT matrix with two axes. Equations and Variables. Equations are numbered 1 to 35 and also variables.

But I am not able to find out the actual variable name from the numbers.

I tried looking at the OneMass_info.json file but the number of variables and equations there are much higher than the BLT matrix and somehow the numbers do not match with the numbers found on the BLT matrix.

is there any way to fish out only those equations and variables shown in the BLT matrix?

Comment: Have you tried the Transformational Debugger from OMEdit? It can show you in which equation a variable is solved.
Or do you need the BLT matrix itself?

Comment: I needed the BLT matrix itself and the variables and equations represented in its two axes. For example, if I take the BLT Matrix for Modelica>Thermal>Fluidflow>Onemass, there are around 40 equations and Equation 3 is connected to var_18. But in the transformational debugger, there are 270 odd equations and when I open equation 3, no variable can be seen. 
I am specifically interested in those equations and variables that finally end up in the BLT matrix

Comment: The best I found is `-d=dumpeqninorder` in that case. A bit of post-processing regex magic and you should have a decent list of equations and variables for your axis.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest to use the Transformational Debugger from OMEdit to analyze the matching instead. In the `Variables Browser` you can select model variables and see in which equation the variable is defined. So the information is the same as in the BLT dump, but actually readable. I'm not sure if the indices correspond to the html dump produced by `-d=bltmatrixdump`.

[image]

If you need something machine readable it is also possible to parse the `MODELNAME_info.json` yourself. That is basically what the Debugger is doing.

If you really need the BLT matrix itself you can use debug flag
`-d=dumpeqninorder` to get the equations in order and which variable is solved in that equation.

Comment: If I use the Transformational debugger for matching, does that mean the BLT matrix has to be generated from it by hand?

The index of the OM generated BLT Matrix equations and variables and the index of equations in the Transformational debugger are somehow not matching. So I am not able to understand which variables are connected to which equations in the BLT matrix

Comment: From what I can see the indices in the transformational debugger are offset by the number of initial equations. But you could also use `-d=dumpeqninorder` and run regex  `/(?<=: )(.*)(?=:VARIABLE)` on the output to get only the names of the varaibles in order, see https://regex101.com/r/uHRM7F/1.